# Google chart export in to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, svg, export

I need to export a `Google chart` into PDF file. But in   [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/_iUUzeO1R7Y)   says that, There is no way to directly export the charts as a PDF, but we can convert them to png images and import the image files into a PDF. So I converted `svg` format (google chart format)  into `png` format.

My question is : Can I export this `png` image (streaming) directly into `PDF` with out saving in a physical path? If yes how it implement.

My language is java and java script as client side.

I searched many questions in this but doesn't get solution match for my issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library? They have exampes how to [add image on page](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/pdf/itext/insert-image.html). And even they use .jpg, nevertheless, I think you can change it for .png.

---

P.S. I'm looking this issue to. Changing chart to image and then set it in PDF - is the first way, but as I understand, there is another one - using HTML to convert it to pdf. So, now I'm trying to create html with charts, which will be converted in pdf format.

Comment: we cannot export google chart api by using iText. I already converted chart into png format, in js side there is code like   var htmlString ='<html><body>Hello world</body></html>';
                 
                     var doc = new jsPDF();
                     doc.fromHTML(htmlString,100,100,{});
                     doc.output('datauri');   but by using this an error occur like "jsPDFAPI is undefined". I already include js file jspdf.js,jspdf.plugin.addimage.js,jspdf.plugin.from_html.js :(

Comment: Yes, we cannot export google chart api using iText, but you say you've already converted it to .png. So, Can you add it to your html? 
And I use example to convert HTML to pdf  from [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-html-to-pdf-using-itext.html) which use iText+XMLWorker. Are your try it?

Comment: how to send the image stream into java?